# T SQL use case when in parameter

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to set the variable value with a case statement to determine the financial year, depending on the month but I get a Null value returned for the financial year:

```
declare
@Costcentre varchar(50)
,@dt date
,@dty int
,@dtm int

select @Costcentre = 'CAM'
SELECT @dt = '2012-09-30'
select @dtm = DATEPART(month,@dt)
select 
@dty = case when @dtm between 4 and 12 then DATEPART(year,@dt) + 1 end
,@dty = case when @dtm between 1 and 3 then DATEPART(year,@dt) end


select @dty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to assign `@dty` once:

```
select  @dty = case 
    when @dtm between 4 and 12 then DATEPART(year,@dt) + 1 
    when @dtm between 1 and 3 then DATEPART(year,@dt) 
end
```

Otherwise, you're just overwriting `@dty` if `@dtm` isn't between 1 and 3.